# spring and angulaJS(i am getting error like HTTP Status 404 )

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I am getting an `HTTP Status 404` error in my controller.

#### Server code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showMsg/",
method=RequestMethod.GET,produces=
{
"application/json"
})'

public ResponseBody String show(){
    HashMap hash = new HashMap();
    hash.put("msg", "welcome to spring angular js");
    return hash;
}
```

#### AngularJS code

```
$http.get('HelloWorld/showMsg').success(function(data){
    alert("Success");
}).error(function(data){
    alert("Error");
});
```

I get an `HTTP Status 404` error.

Comment: It's clear that your URL is wrong. Can you show the complete class?

Answer (score 0):

URL is wrong in this case.

Define correct URL something like below:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/HelloWorld/showMsg')
```